# How do I add ejs to a src object of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

EJS Code:

`<img class="card-img-top" alt="..."><%= articles.image %><img>`

Server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const router = require('./routes/article')

app.use('articles', router)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const articles = [{
        title: 'Test Article',
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        quickDescription: 'quick description',
        image: '<img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1148215519724441600/1148217149928767528/New_Project_1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">'
    }]
    res.render('index', { articles: articles })
})

app.listen(5000)
```

Everything works, even when I define articles.title or something like the description, I'm just not sure how to include the ejs articles.image into my img src object.

I tried everything but nothing worked really.

Comment: Did you try string literal? For example,`<img src="${articles.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some solutions to do that.

### solution 1: render `HTML` string

> use `<%-` outputs the unescaped value into the template.

```js
<body>
  <div>
    <% articles.forEach(function(article) { %>
      <div>
        <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
        image <%- article.image %>
      </div>
    <% }); %>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
// ...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const articles = [{
    title: 'Test Article',
    image: '<img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1148215519724441600/1148217149928767528/New_Project_1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">',
  }]
  res.render('index', { articles: articles })
})
// ...
```

### solution 2: render `string` value

> use `<%=` outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)

```js
<body>
  <div>
    <% articles.forEach(function(article) { %>
      <div>
        <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="<%= article.url %>" />
      </div>
    <% }); %>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
// ...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const articles = [{
    title: 'Test Article',
    image: '<img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1148215519724441600/1148217149928767528/New_Project_1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">',
    // if you can get the image URL ✅
    url: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1148215519724441600/1148217149928767528/New_Project_1.png',
  }]
  res.render('index', { articles: articles })
})
// ...
```

### refs

https://ejs.co/#docs